Weird Redis timeout
I'm having a weird Redis cache timeout on a client. Why weird? It's because the application (a REST service) is running 2 instances on 2 identical VMs thru a load balancer. One box never has any Redis client timeouts, the 2d one is experiencing timeouts at different times of the day. The timeout is set at 7s seconds. but notice this timeout message: Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 13047ms elapsed, timeout is 7000ms), command=GET.
While most timeout messages occur between 7 and 8 seconds, a number of them happen at much later interval ( see above timeout message).
The CPU never goes about 30% and memory is at 80%.
Could a hypervisor (since it's a VM) indicate any issues?
Followed thru Redis client timeout recommendations (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeout). Also, followed Azure based recommendations for the client timeout issues. Increased timeout from 5 to 7 seconds. No luck.
Check Redis server to slow clients. No issues there at all.
Updated StackExchange.Redis client library to the latest version.

Have you checked a) the Redis log or b) the Redis health from the CLI?

yep. checked redis health. CPU @25%. 0 errors. Besides, if the errors occured in Redis server then errors would appear in both Redis clients. However, only 1 box is having errors and another is having none.
